Wifi calling sometimes gets turned off
I don't know why but sometimes the setting for wifi calling gets turned off. The phone is rooted but I don't think that should make a difference. I was wondering if there's a way to use Tasker to help somehow, even just having a widget to turn it on would be better than having to go to the settings each time. How can I use Tasker to turn on wifi calling, does anyone know the shell command to do it?
